# How to make mongoose.find not return all data if passed with empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**I have Videos data with title name on each and writing an search api which will get videos data matching title name**

```js
    exports.findbytitle = (req, res) => {
      let userPattern = new RegExp(req.body.title, "i");
      Videos.find({ title: userPattern })
        .then((video) => {
          res.send({ success: true, video });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.send({ success: false, err });
        });
    };
```

Problem here is if `userPattern` matches I get proper videos, but if `userPattern` is empty string example: (`"title": ""`) I get all videos instead of error.
What changes should I make to get error if `userPattern` is passed as empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw custom error if `req.body.title` is not sent or is empty string:

```js
exports.findbytitle = (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.body.title) return res.status(400).json({success:false, message: 'Title is missing.'})
  let userPattern = new RegExp(req.body.title, "i");
  Videos.find({ title: userPattern })
    .then((video) => {
      res.send({ success: true, video });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send({ success: false, err });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As you know only if the title is empty then why aren't you adding a condition before query?

```
if(!req.body.title) {
   return res.send({ success: false, err: new Error("Not found")})
}
```

Comment: just learning conditional statements and how to write apis.